# DNX: The current runtime target framework is not compatible with project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnx, .net-4.6, dnvm

I am getting the following run-time error:

```
[InvalidOperationException: The current runtime target framework is not compatible with 'TestDeployProject'.

Current runtime Target Framework: 'DNX,Version=v4.5 (dnx45)'
  Type: CLR
  Architecture: x86
  Version: 1.0.0-beta6-12256

Please make sure the runtime matches a framework specified in project.json]
```

**Project settings DNX SDK version:**

[image: Solution DNX SDK version]

**`project.json` target frameworks:**

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx46": { }
},
```

**DNVM list**:

```
Active Version     Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------     ------- ------------ --------------- -----
       1.0.0-beta6 clr     x64          win
  *    1.0.0-beta6 clr     x86          win             latest
       1.0.0-beta6 coreclr x64          win             default
```

What could be the problem?

EDIT:

I have tried to use dnx451 as specified in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31671851/vs-2015-setting-right-target-framework-for-asp-net-5-web-project). Same problem.  The environmental variable also did not help.

Comment: Same problem if I change to `dnx451`. I've tried setting the `DNX_IIS_RUNTIME_FRAMEWORK` environmental variable as suggest.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look at the `dependencies` section in your `project.json`.  You will get this error if your ASP.NET packages are not at `beta6`.

`"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core": "6.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Cors": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-*",
...`

Yesterday I upgraded two projects from beta4 to beta6.  Accidentally left the dependencies of one at beta4, but with `global.json` sdk set to beta6, and I got this exact error when running it.

Comment: This was the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: I used File new project, after running dnvm upgrade. I had 75 build errors in the migrations folder when I did a replace all "beta5" with "beta6". Did you run into that?

Comment: @Aligned there are many api changes to ASP.NET5 MVC6 as it progresses.  Migrating code from one beta version to the next will require addressing these issues.  You can find a [list of breaking changes here](https://github.com/aspnet/announcements/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=)