# I can not start the project with Asp.Net MVC 6 and DNX

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I created an empty project AspNet MVC 6, and chose .Net 4.6

My **project.json** file:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ]
}
```

**dnvm list**:

```
Active Version     Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------     ------- ------------ --------------- -----
       1.0.0-beta4 clr     x64          win
       1.0.0-beta4 clr     x86          win
       1.0.0-beta4 coreclr x64          win
       1.0.0-beta4 coreclr x86          win
       1.0.0-beta5 clr     x64          win
       1.0.0-beta5 clr     x86          win
       1.0.0-beta5 coreclr x64          win
       1.0.0-beta5 coreclr x86          win
       1.0.0-beta6 clr     x86          win             default
```

When I run the project I get the following **error**:

> The current runtime target framework is not compatible with
>   'WebApplication20'.
>
> Current runtime Target Framework: 'DNX,Version=v4.5 (dnx45)'  Type:
>   CLR  Architecture: x86  Version: 1.0.0-beta6-12256
>
> Please make sure the runtime matches a framework specified in
>   project.json

**Where is my mistake?**

Comment: I think you should switch to coreclr.

Comment: Please tell me how can I do it?

Comment: `dnvm use 1.0.0-beta5 -r coreclr -arch x86` if this doesn't help it is good idea to share global.json too.

Comment: It did not help...
**global.json**
`{
    "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
    "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "runtime": "clr",
        "architecture": "x86"
    }
}
`

Comment: edit `"runtime": "clr" -> "runtime": "coreclr"` and `"version": "1.0.0-beta6" -> "version": "1.0.0-beta5"`

Comment: This has led to new errors!   http://f6.s.qip.ru/jjb2KBl4.png There are some options?

Comment: I solved this problem! Here is the answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31744682/dnx-the-current-runtime-target-framework-is-not-compatible-with-project   Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple versions installed, you need to only have one version [of the runtime installed.](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/master/known-issues-vs2015.md#missing-sdk)

after `dnvm uninstall` deleted all files in %USERPROFILE%.dnx\packages *(only do this after uninstalling from programs and features)*

> `dnvm list`
>
> `dnvm upgrade` or `upgrade-self`