# How to change the target framework version of asp 5 project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

When creating a project in VS2015 it asks you the target .NET framework version. I chose .NET 4.6 but now I want to revert back to 4.5. In the past, you were able to change the target framework version from the project tab but now in asp 5 it seems like there is no way to do it ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the target framework you need to change the dnx entry in **project.json**. You can upgrade from 4.5.1 to 4.6 by changing "**dnx451**" to "**dnx46**".

Be aware that there are still some problems running latest framework version in web environment. E.g. IIS not picking up .NET 4.6 and running in 4.5.1 by default as explained in this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31671851/vs-2015-setting-right-target-framework-for-asp-net-5-web-project/31687529#answer-31687529) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project (not solution) `->` select properties `->` under Application tab select Target Framework `->` change to desired framework.