# New ASP.NET 5 preview project fails to run

Tags: asp.net-core

I created a new ASP.NET 5 preview project in VS 2015 RTM (fully updated). When I try to debug it, it fails with the following exception:

> The current runtime target framework is not compatible with
>   'ProjectName'.
>
> Current runtime Target Framework: 'DNX,Version=v4.5 (dnx45)'  Type:
>   CLR  Architecture: x86  Version: 1.0.0-beta6-12256
>
> Please make sure the runtime matches a framework specified in
>   project.json

I went with the default settings in the new project dialog, which I believe included a dependency on .NET 4.5.1 (though there's no mention of that dependency in the project.json file - contrary to what the exception message claims). I tried the [solution offered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31671851/vs-2015-setting-right-target-framework-for-asp-net-5-web-project) (defining the DNX_IIS_RUNTIME_FRAMEWORK  environment variable in the project's debug settings) without success.

Comment: Can you post your project.json?

Comment: Have you installed the tooling updates mentioned here? https://github.com/aspnet/Home/releases

Answer (score 0):

Install latest tools and try again. Beta 6 isn't apt to be supported and lots changed since then. You can get the tools here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49442