# Understanding ASP.NET Core Dependencies and Capabilities

Tags: asp.net-core

When I use a Visual Studio 2015 template to create a brand-new ASP.NET Core project, I see a couple of unexpected pieces.  I'd like to understand these:

- By default, the new project targets `dnxcore50` and `dnx451`.  I thought ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6 required .net 4.6, so I don't know why `dnx451` is one of the default targets.
- Regardless of dnx target, the startup.cs file specifies `app.UseIISPlatformHandler`.  I've been running the `dnxcore50` target in Docker (i.e. Linux) without any problem, even though Linux does not have IIS.  So I don't know what `UseIISPlatformHandler` does.  I can find no documentation for it either.

Can anyone clarify?

Comment: Could you tag my answer as the answer so it's easier for other SO users to find please? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

- Why dnx451 instead of dnx46 is basically IIS's fault, see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31671851/vs-2015-setting-right-target-framework-for-asp-net-5-web-project). Also perhaps the templates run behind because Azure has not yet switched to 4.6? Just a little theory of mine. I'm not sure.
- UseIISPatformHandler is again only used for IIS. You can savely remove it if you have no interest in publishing your web app to IIS. You can learn more about the HTTP Platform Handler (which IIS needs) [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/The-HTTP-Platform-Handler-with-Scott-Hanselman). And you can learn more about the IIS Platform Handler Middleware from the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/blob/c93e4f09f2e5648c70bfa86748911f7ea0c18148/src/Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler/IISPlatformHandlerMiddleware.cs).

Does this make it more clear?