# Error with TargetFramework='dnx46' in .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am tring to run a open source project made in .NET, I do not have enough knowledgement now about this framework, but I have researched for run this project.

In the process appears an error but I have not found how to fix it in the documentation, forums and this site. I tried to modify the value `dnx46` the rebuid is correct but the moment of run does not work and generate an server errror. Someone know about this error in console when I try to rebuild solution

```
Cannot infer TargetFrameworkIdentifier and/or TargetFrameworkVersion from TargetFramework='dnx46'. They must be specified explicitly
```

The image of console is [image]

Comment: I would suggest reading through this Q/A: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31671851/74757

Comment: Check with the authors. dnx46 is obsolete now, and the code must be patched.

Comment: Thank you @Cᴏʀʏ . I did the instructions that the post says but did not work for me and other people that have written in the comments

Comment: Thanks @LexLi , I posted the question in the issue about it in the Github forum of authors

Answer (score 1):

`dnx46` was part of the original RC for .NET Core.  It has been deprecated and documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/migration/from-dnx#migrating-the-project-file

> If you are using other dnx targets, like `dnx451` you will need to change those as well. `dnx451` should be changed to `net451`.

You'll want to update your target frarmework to `net46`.